# Rotate XYZ frame in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

Given a `XYZ` frame in 3D space at origin `O(0,0,0)`. And given a plane equation:

`L = 0.5774x + 0.1155y + 0.8083z = 0`.

I need to derive the matrix which rotate the XYZ frame until Z-axis is vertical to the plane `L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plane is given by the equation
$$
L = 0.5774 x + 0.1155 y + 0.8083 z = 0 
$$

from this one can derive the normal vector

$$
n = \frac{(0.5774, 0.1155, 0.8083)^t}{|(0.5774, 0.1155, 0.8083)^t|}
= (0.5774, 0.1155, 0.8083)^t
$$

Thus $L$ was already given as

$$
L = n \cdot r = 0
$$

for a vector $r = (x,y,z)^t$.

Looking for a vector $u = (1, y, 0)^t \in L$:

$$
u \in L \iff 
n \cdot u = 
n_x + n_y y = 0 \iff 
y = -\frac{n_x}{n_y} = -5
\iff u = (1, -5, 0)^t \\
n_u = \frac{u}{|u|} = (0.19612,-0.98058, 0)^t 
$$

So we have the normal unit vector $n$ of the plane and a unit vector $n_u$ within the plane.
Looking for another unit vector $n_v \perp n_u \wedge n_v \perp n$:

$$
n_v = n_u \times n = \epsilon_{i,j,k} \, e_i \, n_{u j} \, n_k
= (-0.79260, -0.15852, 0.58884)^t
$$

That is a nice orthonormal system, with two vectors in the plane, and one perpendicular to it.

The matrix
$$
R = (n_u, n_v, n)
$$

fullfills

$$
R e_x = n_u \quad R e_y = n_v \quad R e_z = n
$$

where $e_x = (1, 0, 0)^t$, $e_y = (0,1,0)^t$ and $e_z = (0, 0, 1)^t$.

However $\det(R) = -1$, which means this is not a proper rotation, therefore we switch to 
$$
R = (n_v, n_u, n) =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-0.79260 &  0.19612 &  0.57740 \\
  -0.15852 & -0.98058 &  0.11550 \\
   0.58884 &  0.00000 &  0.80830
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: Are quaternions relevant to this?

Comment: That is usually just a different packaging. The quaternion product can be expressed in terms of scalar and vector product for example.

Comment: Why you assumed the x-component in `u` vector equal 1  (`u=[1;y;0]`)?

Comment: Just to pick a vector from the plane, it could have been any non-zero value. The normalization would shrink it properly and the vector product would pick another partner. There was no restriction to a specific pair within the plane.

Answer (score 0):

You have single condition to have the Z axis oriented the same direction as the normal of the plane. Which means, that you'll have infinitely many possibilities.

You have the vector of $Z$ axis $\vec{z}$ and vector of the normal of the plane $\vec{n}$.
If you rotate the coordinate system around the vector $\vec{z} + \vec{n}$ by $\pi$, you'll have the Z axis to the original direction of normal vector.

I used that in OpenGL, where is a nice function glRotatef.

If you want some specific orientation of XY plane, you'll have to rotate again around the Z axis.